# A JavaScript plugin for rendering radial pie charts

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, plugin

(See also [An extended JavaScript plugin for rendering radial pie charts](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286745/an-extended-javascript-plugin-for-rendering-radial-pie-charts).)

I have this JavaScript plugin:

**`rodde-radial-pie-chart.js:`**

```
class RadialPieChart {
    
    static #rgb_alphabet_set = new Set();

    #canvas_id;
    #entries = [];
    #maximum_radius;
    #start_angle;
    #empty_pie_chart_color = "";
    #canvas_background_color = "";

    static {
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("0");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("1");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("2");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("3");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("4");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("5");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("6");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("7");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("8");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("9");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("a");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("b");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("c");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("d");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("e");
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("f");
    }

    constructor(canvas_id,
                maximum_radius = 100,
                start_angle = 0.0, 
                empty_pie_chart_color = "#000",
                canvas_background_color = "#fff") {

        this.#canvas_id = canvas_id;

        this.#maximum_radius = 
            RadialPieChart.#validateMaximumRadius(maximum_radius);

        start_angle %= 360.0;

        if (start_angle < 0.0) {
            start_angle += 360.0;
        }

        this.#start_angle = start_angle;

        this.#empty_pie_chart_color = 
            RadialPieChart.#validateColor(empty_pie_chart_color);

        this.#canvas_background_color =
            RadialPieChart.#validateColor(canvas_background_color); 
    }
    
    addEntry(value, color) {
        const entry = {
            "value": RadialPieChart.#validateValue(value),
            "color": RadialPieChart.#validateColor(color)
        };

        this.#entries.push(entry);
    }

    getMaximumRadius() {
        return this.#maximum_radius;
    }

    getStartAngle() {
        return this.#start_angle;
    }

    getValueAt(index) {
        this.#checkIndex(index);
        return this.#entries[index]["value"];
    }

    getColorAt(index) {
        this.#checkIndex(index);
        return this.#entries[index]["color"];
    }

    setStartAngle(start_angle) {
        this.#start_angle = start_angle;
        this.#start_angle %= 360.0;

        if (this.#start_angle < 0.0) {
            this.#start_angle += 360.0;
        }
    }

    setMaximumRadius(new_maximum_radius) {
        this.#validateValue(new_maximum_radius);
        this.#maximum_radius = new_maximum_radius;
    }

    setValueAt(index, new_value) {
        this.#checkIndex(index);
        this.#entries[index]["value"] = this.#validateValue(new_value);
    }

    setColorAt(index, new_color) {
        this.#checkIndex(index);
        this.#entries[index]["color"] = this.#validateColor(new_color);
    }

    removeEntry(index) {
        if (this.#entries.length === 0) {
            throw "Removing from an empty list.";
        }

        this.#checkIndex(index);
        this.#entries.splice(index, 1);
    }

    render() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById(this.#canvas_id);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.canvas.width  = this.#maximum_radius * 2;
        ctx.canvas.height = this.#maximum_radius * 2;

        // Fill the entire chart background:
        ctx.fillStyle = this.#canvas_background_color;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

        if (this.#entries.length === 0) {
            // Once here, there is no entries in the list.
            // Just fill the circle with empty_pie_chart_color:
            this.#fillEmptyCircle(ctx);
        } else {
            this.#renderEntries(ctx);
        }
    }
    
    static #validateValue(value) {
        if (value < 0) {
            throw "Value (" + value + ") can not be negative.";
        }
        
        return value;
    }
    
    static #validateColor(color) {
        color = color.trim().toLowerCase();
        
        if (color.length != 4 && color.length != 7) {
            throw "Invalid color string. Color string of length "
                    + color.length
                    + ". Must be 4 or 7.";
        }
        
        if (color[0] !== "#") {
            throw "Invalid color string. The first character must be " + 
                  "the hash #.";
        }
        
        for (let ch in color) {
            if (!this.#rgb_alphabet_set.has(ch)) {
                throw "Character " + ch + " is not allowed in RGB values.";
            }
        }
        
        return color;
    }

    static #validateMaximumRadius(maximum_radius) {
        if (maximum_radius <= 0) {
            throw "Maximum radius (" + maximum_radius + ") is not positive.";
        }

        return maximum_radius;
    }

    #checkIndex(index) {
        if (this.#entries.length === 0) {
            throw "Indexing an empty list.";
        }

        if (index < 0) {
            throw "Index (" + index + ") cannot be negative.";
        }

        if (index >= this.#entries.length) {
            throw "Index (" + index + ") is too large. Must be at most "
                  + this.#entries.length + ".";
        }
    }

    #fillEmptyCircle(ctx) {
        const width = ctx.canvas.width;
        const height = ctx.canvas.height;
        const centerX = width / 2;
        const centerY = height / 2;
        const radius = width / 2;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(centerX,
                centerY,
                radius,
                0.0,
                2 * Math.PI, 
                false);

        ctx.fillStyle = this.#empty_pie_chart_color;
        ctx.fill();
    }

    #renderEntries(ctx) {
        const angle_per_entry = 360.0 / this.#entries.length;

        for (var i = 0, n = this.#entries.length; i !== n; i++) {
            var entry_start_angle = this.#start_angle + angle_per_entry * i;
            var entry_end_angle = entry_start_angle + angle_per_entry;

            entry_start_angle = Math.PI * (entry_start_angle / 180.0);
            entry_end_angle = Math.PI * (entry_end_angle / 180.0);
            
            this.#drawEntry(ctx,
                            entry_start_angle, 
                            entry_end_angle,
                            this.#entries[i]["value"],
                            this.#entries[i]["color"]);
        }
    }

    #drawEntry(ctx, start_angle, end_angle, value, color) {
        const centerX = this.#maximum_radius;
        const centerY = this.#maximum_radius;
        const maximum_value = this.#findMaximumValue();
        const radius = this.#maximum_radius * (value / maximum_value);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, start_angle, end_angle);
        ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
    }

    #findMaximumValue() {
        var maximum_value = 0;

        for (var i = 0, n = this.#entries.length; i !== n; i++) {
            const tentative_maximum_value = this.#entries[i]["value"];
            maximum_value = Math.max(maximum_value, tentative_maximum_value);
        }

        return maximum_value;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Radial pie chart demo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="radial-pie-chart-canvas"></canvas>
        <script src="rodde-radial-pie-chart.js"></script>
        <script>
            let rpc = new RadialPieChart("radial-pie-chart-canvas");
            rpc.setStartAngle(36.0);
            rpc.addEntry(50, "#f00");
            rpc.addEntry(30, "#a257f0")
            rpc.addEntry(25, "#06771f");
            rpc.addEntry(17, "#0ff");
            rpc.addEntry(23, "#ddd");
            rpc.render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

... which looks like this:

[image: screenshot of sample radial pie chart]

**Critique request**

As always, I would like to hear any comments, especially those regarding my JS routine.

Answer (score 2):

Bearing in mind that this code has [successor code in *An extended JavaScript plugin for rendering radial pie charts*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/286745/120114), which appears to have been modified significantly, I still noticed review aspects.

## D.R.Y. it out

It appears a few of your other posts mention concerns about DRYness. It has a bit of redundancy - at least in the `#static` method:

> ```
> static {
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("0");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("1");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("2");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("3");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("4");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("5");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("6");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("7");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("8");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("9");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("a");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("b");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("c");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("d");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("e");
>     this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add("f");
> }
> ```

Those repetitive lines can be simplified using a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop using [`Number.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

```
static {
    for (let i=0; i < 16; i++) {
        this.#rgb_alphabet_set.add(i.toString(16));
    }
}
```

## Consider using `let` instead of `var` when re-assignment is necessary

It is great that `const` is used in many places. There are some variables declared with `var`, which is fine for any variable that needs to be re-assigned - e.g. `i`, `entry_start_angle`, `entry_end_angle`, `maximum_value`, etc. Consider using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to have block- scoped variables instead of function scoped variables.