# An extended JavaScript plugin for rendering radial pie charts

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, plugin

(This post is the continuation of [A JavaScript plugin for rendering radial pie charts](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286712/a-javascript-plugin-for-rendering-radial-pie-charts).)

(See the [continuation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/287236/a-web-component-for-rendering-radial-pie-charts-in-an-html-canvas) of **this** post.)

Now, you can mark up the radial pie charts via XML:

**`index.html:`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Radial pie chart demo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="rodde-radial-pie-chart.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Introduction</h3>
        <rodde-radial-pie-chart start-angle="30" 
                                maximum-radius="200" 
                                empty-pie-chart-color="grey" 
                                canvas-background-color="#333">
            <entry value="100" color="black"></entry>
            <entry value="80" color="#faa"></entry>
            <entry value="50" color="#a12bc3"></entry>
        </rodde-radial-pie-chart>

        <p>Some text here.</p>
        
        <rodde-radial-pie-chart>
            <entry value="100" color="black"></entry>
            <entry value="80" color="red"></entry>
            <entry value="50" color="blue"></entry>
            <entry value="70" color="orange"></entry>
        </rodde-radial-pie-chart>
    </body>
</html>
```

**`rodde-radial-pie-chart.js:`**

```
class RadialPieChart {
    
    #canvas_id;
    #entries = [];
    #maximum_radius;
    #start_angle;
    #empty_pie_chart_color;
    #canvas_background_color;

    constructor(canvas_id,
                maximum_radius = 100,
                start_angle = 0.0, 
                empty_pie_chart_color = "#000",
                canvas_background_color = "#fff") {

        this.#canvas_id = canvas_id;

        this.#maximum_radius = 
            RadialPieChart.#validateMaximumRadius(maximum_radius);

        start_angle %= 360.0;

        if (start_angle < 0.0) {
            start_angle += 360.0;
        }

        this.#start_angle = start_angle;
        this.#empty_pie_chart_color = empty_pie_chart_color;
        this.#canvas_background_color = canvas_background_color; 
    }
    
    addEntry(value, color) {
        const entry = {
            "value": RadialPieChart.#validateValue(value),
            "color": color
        };

        this.#entries.push(entry);
    }

    getMaximumRadius() {
        return this.#maximum_radius;
    }

    getStartAngle() {
        return this.#start_angle;
    }

    getValueAt(index) {
        this.#checkIndex(index);
        return this.#entries[index]["value"];
    }

    getColorAt(index) {
        this.#checkIndex(index);
        return this.#entries[index]["color"];
    }

    setStartAngle(start_angle) {
        this.#start_angle = start_angle;
        this.#start_angle %= 360.0;

        if (this.#start_angle < 0.0) {
            this.#start_angle += 360.0;
        }
    }

    setMaximumRadius(new_maximum_radius) {
        this.#validateValue(new_maximum_radius);
        this.#maximum_radius = new_maximum_radius;
    }

    setValueAt(index, new_value) {
        this.#checkIndex(index);
        this.#entries[index]["value"] = this.#validateValue(new_value);
    }

    setColorAt(index, new_color) {
        this.#checkIndex(index);
        this.#entries[index]["color"] = new_color;
    }

    removeEntry(index) {
        if (this.#entries.length === 0) {
            throw "Removing from an empty list.";
        }

        this.#checkIndex(index);
        this.#entries.splice(index, 1);
    }

    render() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById(this.#canvas_id);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.canvas.width  = this.#maximum_radius * 2;
        ctx.canvas.height = this.#maximum_radius * 2;

        // Fill the entire chart background:
        ctx.fillStyle = this.#canvas_background_color;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

        if (this.#entries.length === 0) {
            // Once here, there is no entries in the list.
            // Just fill the circle with empty_pie_chart_color:
            this.#fillEmptyCircle(ctx);
        } else {
            this.#renderEntries(ctx);
        }
    }
    
    static #validateValue(value) {
        if (value < 0) {
            throw "Value (" + value + ") can not be negative.";
        }
        
        return value;
    }

    static #validateMaximumRadius(maximum_radius) {
        if (maximum_radius <= 0) {
            throw "Maximum radius (" + maximum_radius + ") is not positive.";
        }

        return maximum_radius;
    }

    #checkIndex(index) {
        if (this.#entries.length === 0) {
            throw "Indexing an empty list.";
        }

        if (index < 0) {
            throw "Index (" + index + ") cannot be negative.";
        }

        if (index >= this.#entries.length) {
            throw "Index (" + index + ") is too large. Must be at most "
                  + this.#entries.length + ".";
        }
    }

    #fillEmptyCircle(ctx) {
        const width = ctx.canvas.width;
        const height = ctx.canvas.height;
        const centerX = width / 2;
        const centerY = height / 2;
        const radius = width / 2;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(centerX,
                centerY,
                radius,
                0.0,
                2 * Math.PI, 
                false);

        ctx.fillStyle = this.#empty_pie_chart_color;
        ctx.fill();
    }

    #renderEntries(ctx) {
        const angle_per_entry = 360.0 / this.#entries.length;

        for (var i = 0, n = this.#entries.length; i !== n; i++) {
            var entry_start_angle = -90.0 + this.#start_angle + angle_per_entry * i;
            var entry_end_angle = entry_start_angle + angle_per_entry;

            this.#drawEntry(ctx,
                            entry_start_angle, 
                            entry_end_angle,
                            this.#entries[i]["value"],
                            this.#entries[i]["color"]);
        }
    }

    #drawEntry(ctx, start_angle, end_angle, value, color) {
        const centerX = this.#maximum_radius;
        const centerY = this.#maximum_radius;
        const maximum_value = this.#findMaximumValue();
        const radius = this.#maximum_radius * (value / maximum_value);

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(centerX, 
                centerY,
                radius, 
                (start_angle / 180.0) * Math.PI, 
                (end_angle / 180.0) * Math.PI);

        ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
    }

    #findMaximumValue() {
        var maximum_value = 0;

        for (var i = 0, n = this.#entries.length; i !== n; i++) {
            const tentative_maximum_value = this.#entries[i]["value"];
            maximum_value = Math.max(maximum_value, tentative_maximum_value);
        }

        return maximum_value;
    }
}

function populatePieChartWithEntries(rpc, pie_chart) {
    const entries = pie_chart.getElementsByTagName("entry");

    for (var i = 0, n = entries.length; i !== n; i++) {
        const entry = entries[i];
        const value = entry.getAttribute("value");
        const color = entry.getAttribute("color");
        rpc.addEntry(value, color);
    }
}

function getRadialPieChartCanvasID(number) {
    return "radial-pie-chart-canvas-id-" + number;
}

function typesetSinglePieChart(pie_chart, number) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.id = getRadialPieChartCanvasID(number);

    pie_chart.appendChild(canvas);

    const start_angle = pie_chart.getAttribute("start-angle") || 0;
    const maximum_radius = pie_chart.getAttribute("maximum-radius") || 100;

    canvas.width = maximum_radius * 2;
    canvas.height = maximum_radius * 2;

    const empty_pie_chart_color = 
        pie_chart.getAttribute("empty-pie-chart-color") || "#000";

    const canvas_background_color = 
        pie_chart.getAttribute("canvas-background-color") || "#fff";

    const rpc = new RadialPieChart(canvas.id,
                                   maximum_radius,
                                   start_angle, 
                                   empty_pie_chart_color,
                                   canvas_background_color);

    populatePieChartWithEntries(rpc, pie_chart);
    rpc.render();
}

function typesetAllPieCharts() {
    const pie_charts = document.getElementsByTagName("rodde-radial-pie-chart");
    var number = 1;

    for (var i = 0, n = pie_charts.length; i !== n; i++) {
        typesetSinglePieChart(pie_charts[i], number++);
    }
}

typesetAllPieCharts();
```

**Critique request**

As always, please tell me anything that comes to mind.

**Demo output**

You can see the result of the above [here](https://coderodde.github.io/radial-pie-chart-demo.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, that isn't "XML". Those are custom HTML elements.

Most of the code in `typesetSinglePieChart` belongs in the constructor.

- You don't need the default values there, because you already have them on the constructor parameters.
- Creating, attaching and sizing the canvas can be done there.
- `populatePieChartWithEntries` belongs inside the constructor, too.

You don't need to assign an ID to the canvas. Store the reference to the canvas directly instead of its ID in the class.

Instead of attaching your class to the custom HTML elements yourself, consider creating a [web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components).

It is convention to use `camelCase` for variables instead of `snake_case`, e.g. `emptyPieChartColor`.